# Remove specific HTML div when click on delete button using vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, frontend

So I have some input fields which are repetitive to fill different data. For every repetition, I also have a delete button. If I click on this delete button, then all the input fields related to this delete button should be removed. But this delete button is not working.

**HTML**

```
<div v-for="index in 10" class="form-group row" for="switch-id2" v-if="isShow2">
    <br><br>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <b-form-fieldset>
            <label>Pincode</label>
            <div id="app">
                <treeselect placeholder="Enter the pincode(s)" :options="options" :value="value"
                    :multiple="multiple">
                    <div slot="value-label" slot-scope="{ node }">{{ customLabel }}</div>
                </treeselect>
                <p>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="multiple">Multi-select</label>
                </p>
            </div>
        </b-form-fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Supply Chain</label>
        <b-input-group>
            <select class="form-control" id="supplyChain" name="supplyChain" v-model="supplyChain">
                <option selected value="">Select</option>
                <option value="b2bRegular">Dummy</option>
            </select>
        </b-input-group>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>ODA category</label>
        <b-input-group>
            <select class="form-control" id="odaCategory" name="odaCategory" v-model="odaCategory">
                <option selected value="">Select</option>
                <option value="nonODA">Default</option>
            </select>
        </b-input-group>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>ODA TAT</label>
        <b-input-group>
            <select class="form-control" id="odaTat" name="odaTat" v-model="odaTat">
                <option selected value="">Select</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
        </b-input-group>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>FM Facility</label>
        <b-input-group>
            <select class="form-control" id="fmFacility" name="fmFacility" v-model="fmFacility">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </b-input-group>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>LM Facility</label>
        <b-input-group>
            <select class="form-control" id="lmFacility" name="lmFacility" v-model="lmFacility">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </b-input-group>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top:-2em; margin-left:0em">
        <label>RTO Facility</label>
        <b-input-group>
            <select class="form-control" id="rtoFacility" name="rtoFacility" v-model="rtoFacility">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </b-input-group>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top:-2em; margin-left:0em">
        <label>RVP Facility</label>
        <b-input-group>
            <select class="form-control" id="rvpFacility" name="rvpFacility" v-model="rvpFacility">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </b-input-group>
    </div>
    <b-button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete pincode" style="font-size: 20px;"
        onClick=""><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
    </b-button>
</div>
```

**JS code**

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import VueElementLoading from 'vue-element-loading';
import Treeselect from '@riophae/vue-treeselect'
import '@riophae/vue-treeselect/dist/vue-treeselect.css'

export default {
  name: 'dummy',
  components: { VueElementLoading, Treeselect },
  data() {
    return {
      isShow2: true,
      multiple: true,
      value: null,
      options: [203207, 234567, 324353, 201301, 201303, 122413].map(i => ({
        id: i,
        label: `${i}`,
        customLabel: `Custom Label ${i}`,
      })),
    }
  },
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  mounted() {

  },
  methods: {
    thisFileUpload() {
      document.getElementById("file").click();
    }
}
}
```

In the image, if I click the red delete button then Pincode, Supply chain,ODA TAT, FM facility, LM facility, RTo facility, RVP facility input fields should be removed.

[image: In the image, if I click the red delete button then Pincode, Supply chain,ODA TAT, FM facility, LM facility, RTo facility, RVP facility input fields should be removed.]

Comment: Your delete button's `onClick` should just set a state variable inside `data()`. Then use `v-if` on the elements to control whether they appear based on that variable.

Comment: @DanielBeck I tried and it's working, but the problem I'm facing with this solution is, that if I'm clicking any one delete button then all of the input fields visible in the above picture are deleted.

Comment: Then don't put those input fields inside something you're hiding with the delete button. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯    Put the `v-if` only on the elements you actually want to hide

Comment: @DanielBeck Actually, I'm iterating the same elements 10 times. Then, I want to delete only ones, so the other 9 should be visible to me. But as per your first logic, all elements are deleted but I want the remaining 9 components if I am deleting only ones.

Comment: Just a notice: Using v-for together with v-if on te same element is not recommended: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the discussion in comments above, I was not understanding that you're trying to control the visibility of individual rows separately.

The basic answer is still the same:  have your "delete" button set a state variable, and use that state variable to control the visibility of the element you want deleted.

The difference is that if you're controlling the visibility of ten different things, you need ten different state variables.

Typically your state data would already be in an array structure, since you're presumably going to be wanting to put different data in each of these rows; instead of this kind of shortcut

`<div v-for="index in 10" ...>`

you would have something like

```
data() {
    return {
      rowData: [
         {isShown: true, /* other data for this row here */},
         {isShown: true, /* other data for this row here */},
         {isShown: true, /* other data for this row here */},
         /* ...and so on */
      ],
```

and your render loop would iterate over that rowData array (remembering that you shouldn't have `v-for` and `v-if` [on the same element](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for-with-v-if)):

```
<template v-for="(row, index) in rowData">
  <div v-if="row.isShown">
    /* ... */
    <button v-click="hideRow(index)">Delete</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

The delete button in each row can pass the current row index on to the click handler, so the handler knows which element to update isShown for (by [replacing rowData with a new array](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#array-change-detection) where `rowData[index].isShown` is `false`.)

Comment: Thanks, @DanielBeck. This is exactly what I was searching for.